# Resetting a picklist field

Tags: javascript

I have web form that contains a picklist field called jrole which is hidden.  The field is unhidden based on a certain value selected in another field called custtype.  The issue is the field jrole is used for various combination.  What I want to do is ensure that the default value selected for jrole returns to Select One each time that the controlling field (custtype) is selected.

I have looked at other public posts but can't get a solution working.  This is the code I have so far.

```
$('#custtype').change(function()
var defaultValue = $("#jrole").val("");
var value = this.value;
else if (value == 'Electrical Contractor (Service)') {
    $('#jroleli').removeClass('MMM--isVisuallyHidden');     
    $('#mktsegli').addClass('MMM--isVisuallyHidden');
  $('#checkbox-needed-error-job').removeClass('MMM--isVisuallyHidden');
  $('#checkbox-needed-error-mkt').addClass('MMM--isVisuallyHidden');
```

//should reset jrole to value = "" - not working
      $("#jrole").val(defaultValue);

```
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, looks like your code it´s incomplete and has some compiling error for example else if without related if

Comment: What control are you talking about when you say "picklist"? Including the HTML along with your jQuery code would help answer that question. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it looks like you've omitted a lot of brackets "{}" that are necessary. When you declare a function, it should look like the following:

```
function(...) {
  ...
}
```

Next, your if statement starts as an else if which is incorrect. The correct format for if statements are as follows.

```
// Case 1: one if statement
if(condition) {
  ...
}
// Case 2: an if else statement
if(condition) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
// Case 3: else if statements
if(condition1) {
  ...
} else if (condition2) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Next, you should be using '===' instead of '==' on most occasions, since this is how most people expect equality to behave. Click here to see more information about the use cases of each: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Lastly, you did not close the right parenthesis on your change function.

So with that in mind, I'll take the liberty to reformat you code in a way I think you meant to have typed it:

```
$('#custtype').change(function() {
  var defaultValue = $("#jrole").val("");
  var value = this.value;
  if (value === 'Electrical Contractor (Service)') {
    $('#jroleli').removeClass('MMM--isVisuallyHidden');     
    $('#mktsegli').addClass('MMM--isVisuallyHidden');
    $('#checkbox-needed-error-job').removeClass('MMM--isVisuallyHidden');
    $('#checkbox-needed-error-mkt').addClass('MMM--isVisuallyHidden');
    // $("#jrole").val(defaultValue);
  }
});
```

Based on what you asked, I believe you will have a lot of aid in using the "console.log" for debugging what you were trying to do. One note is that the default value is begin set to your jrole being assigned the value "". Perhaps you meant the following line to get the default value?

```
var defaultValue = $("#jrole").val(); // retrieve the value from jrole
```

Lastly, if you just wanted to reset the value of jrole, the following line works as you expect.

```
$("#jrole").val(""); // Sets the value to ""
```

But since you did not explain what you mean by "Select One", I'm not sure how to fix the problem you are asking, but I believe these print statements should put you on the right track as to what to expect. Consider the following code for debugging.

```
$('#custtype').change(function() {
  console.log("inside custtype change function"); // does this function ever execute?
  //var defaultValue = $("#jrole").val(""); // by passing in "", you are resetting jrole here, do you need to reset it again down below?
  //console.log(defaultValue); // is this the value you want?
  var defaultValue = ""; // placing this here to be the default value you likely expected
  var value = this.value;
  console.log(value) // is this the value you are expecting?
  if (value === 'Electrical Contractor (Service)') {
    console.log('inside if statement'); // did you aim to be inside this if statement?
    $('#jroleli').removeClass('MMM--isVisuallyHidden');     
    $('#mktsegli').addClass('MMM--isVisuallyHidden');
    $('#checkbox-needed-error-job').removeClass('MMM--isVisuallyHidden');
    $('#checkbox-needed-error-mkt').addClass('MMM--isVisuallyHidden');
    //should reset jrole to value = "" - not working 
    $("#jrole").val(defaultValue); // this will set the value of jrole to default value
  } else {
    console.log('inside else statement'); // do you need logic if it isn't true?
  }
});
```